# Why the parameter of my method is not defined?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, methods

I've got a problem with calling a method of an object.

That's the script:

```js
let transaction = {
  delete: function(codTransaction){
      console.log(codTransaction);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="transaction.delete(31)">
```

The button and the obj are not in the same js file.

The problem is that "codTransaction" is not defined when the method is called so the script inside the method will not work.

Can you explain me why "codTransaction" is not defined? Ty!

Comment: whats the content of the delete function

Comment: I've tested and it seems fine. Can you show us the functions inside delete method ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. As you can see, no error is thrown here.

Comment: *The button and the obj are not in the same js file.* <-- Why is the HTML in the .js file?

Comment: Check if the script is loaded when you click the button then.

Comment: I'm sorry, the issue was into the PHP script and not into js ^^"